# Get all fields in one collection and specific field in other collection with $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection `timestamps` with 10 fields.
and collection `ie_settings` with 5 fields.

I used `$lookup` to join them but it will return all fields.

And I also try to put `$project` to return specific field.

What I want is display all fields from `timestamps`
and specific field from `ie_settings`

Here's my what I tried:

```
Timestamp.aggregate([
                { $match: {
                        $or: [
                            { current_status: '60min break now' },
                            { current_status: 'Time out' }
                        ],
                        createdAt: { $gte: date_from, $lt: date_to } }
                },
                { $lookup: {
                        from: "individual_employment_settings",
                        localField: "staff_id",
                        foreignField: "staff_id",
                        as: "ie_settings" }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "ie_settings.branch_office": 1
                    }
                }
            ])
```

But it will output `branch_office` only. I don't want to list all `timestamp fields` in the `$project`.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `{                     $addFields: {                         "ie_settings.branch_office": 1}}` in 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timestamp.aggregate([
                { $match: {
                        $or: [
                            { current_status: '60min break now' },
                            { current_status: 'Time out' }
                        ],
                        createdAt: { $gte: date_from, $lt: date_to } }
                },
                { $lookup: {
                        from: "individual_employment_settings",
                        localField: "staff_id",
                        foreignField: "staff_id",
                        as: "ie_settings" }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                         document: "$$ROOT",
                        "ie_settings.branch_office": 1
                    }
                }
            ])
```

Comment: I tried but it also display all fields of both collections.